# MathJax rendering poorly (OS X 10.7 Lion)

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, mathjax

I recently bought a new laptop and I am seeing very poor MathJax rendering. I now see the ugly beast below, rather than the beautifully rendered equations that I saw previously. Is there a simple fix?

---

[image]

Comment: What OS do you use? In case of OS X/Lion, [this might be related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2667/5363)

Comment: Yep, it's OS X 10.7 - the fix in that thread cleared it up. Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest that you elaborate this into a short answer and accept it (I'm not entirely sure which fix worked for you, that is: whether it is Jonas Teuwen's or Zhen Lin's suggestion), so that other Chrome/OS X 10.7 users having the same problem will know what to do?

Comment: Done (more characters...)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug caused by an interaction between MathJax and Mac OS X Lion.

A workaround is to open Font Book (hit Cmd-Space and type "Font Book") and search for "stix" in the search box. Select all of the STIX fonts, and hit the checkbox (circled in red in the image below) to disable them. This will cause MathJax to ignore those fonts when rendering TeX.

[image]

Comment: But won't that cause Lion to ignore these fonts the rest of the time, as well?

Comment: Yes, although that doesn't seem to be a problem for me. Earlier versions of OS X don't ship with those fonts at all, so they can't be that important!

Comment: Woh!  Unimportant?  MathJax uses STIX fonts!  It is just that Lion has a previous version of STIX, and not the current (beta) version that makes MathJax look right.  Or something like that.

Comment: In that case, why does everything look 'normal' when I disable those fonts?

Comment: Because then your computer gets them from MathJax.  See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/ where another fix is proposed: replace STIX fonts with newer version 1.1.0 ... Perhaps when 1.1.0 is out of beta, Lion will automatically make that upgrade?

Comment: Ahh, so MathJax automatically gets the fonts from somewhere else if it can't find them locally? It seems that they *are* unimportant, then!

Answer (score 0):

This should be resolved with the update to the latest MathJax library.